# Changing database table name stops location data from being stored

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin to store locations (lat lng values) in separate columns. I am using the 'DOUBLE' datatype.

I've noticed something strange. If I change my table name from 'locations' to anything else, the lat lng values stop being updated. All the other inputs keep working fine, but the lat lng values do not have any input. If I change the name back to table name back to 'locations', the lat lng values start working again.

I noticed something else that was similar, if I change the column name from 'lng' to 'long', the table stops accepting longitude data. Does phpMyAdmin have automated settings for names like this? What if I want several location tables?

Note that all the data is updated in php through a single UPDATE statement, but only the lat lng values are affected by the table name.

Would appreciate any help.

UPDATE: The problem was actually being caused through an AJAX call which would import the lat lng data from another php file, which is why it wasn't working when the names change. Thanks to those who commented.

Comment: If you change the names, the program inserting the data cannot address the objects anymore, the inserts or updates simply fail. It's like if you change the name (or number) on your postbox, you won't receive any more letters. (Unless the postman knows you're still there. Consider a postman new in the neighborhood who has no idea who is who and has to go by the names (or numbers) on the postbox.)

Comment: `LONG` is a MySQL [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-keywords-5-7.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-L).

Comment: @Nick thanks that's good to know! Still need to figure out how to change the name without affecting the input though.

Comment: @stickybit I am not simply changing the names and refreshing, I change the name of the table and the name in the SQL statement as well. As mentioned before all the other data updates successfully, but the lat lng values only get stored if the name of the table is 'locations'. That is what is so strange.

Comment: Apart from maybe hitting a keyword, that causes some trouble, you must then have missed a spot somewhere, where you didn't rename it. In general you can name your objects what ever you like, it must not be any word(s) that describe the semantics. As long as the name of the object is the same as in the queries (and you don't hit a keyword or miss some basic rules, like not using some special characters) it won't make a difference.

Comment: @stickybit that would make sense but you need to consider that all the other data within the same UPDATE statement keeps working fine, regardless of the name. I believe there is some keyword recognition that is making SQL recognise lat lng data. Another example is that when I change the name of a single column, either 'lat' or 'lng' to anything, they both stop working, as if they both rely on each other to be recognised.

Comment: @stickybit Actually, you were right! I had to look through the code very carefully. There was basically another php file that was linked through ajax that was causing weird problems. Appreciate the help!